# Grails default nullable constraints

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

In my Grails app I have the following command object

```
@Validateable
class CalendarEventCommand {

    @BindingFormat('FestivalType')
    Collection<FestivalType> types
    Date start
    Date end
    MapFocalPoint location
    boolean freeOnly = false
}
```

which is used as the argument to a controller action

```
def getCalendarEvents(CalendarEventCommand calendarEventCommand) {
    if (calendarEventCommand.validate()) {
       log.error "Command errors $calendarEventCommand.errors"

    } else {
       log.warn "Everything is fine"
    }
}
```

In `Config.groovy` I've specified the following as the default constraints

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {

    // apply a max size of 191 chars to String columns to support utf8mb4
    // http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4
    '*'(maxSize: 191)

    // this shared constraint provides a way to override the default above for long text properties
    unlimitedSize(maxSize: Integer.MAX_VALUE)
}
```

If an instance is created with a null value for `start` and `end` validation passes, but I wouldn't expect it to because AFAIK a default constraint of `nullable: false` should be applied to all properties. I've tried adding this explicitly, by changing the first default constraint to

```
'*'(maxSize: 191, nullable: false)
```

But `validate()` still returns `true` when `start` and/or `end` are null. If I add these constraints to `CalendarEventCommand`

```
static constraints = {
    start nullable: false
    end nullable: false
}
```

then `validate()` returns `false`, but AFAIK it shouldn't be necessary for me to add these constraints.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an expected behavior. There are couple of JIRA defects regarding this functionality out of which [GRAILS-7431](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8583) and [GRAILS-8583](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7431) seems more focused towards the behavior.

I was going through [DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/DefaultConstraintEvaluator.java#L238) which takes care of global constraints only for domain classes. I think we have to end up using the way mentioned later.

```
static constraints = {
    start nullable: false
    end nullable: false
}
```